# Почему не заполняется динамический массив?

Tags: массивы, c++

```
# include 
do {
    double *Gpz= new double[hh]; 
    Gpzz = выражение;
    Gpz[i]=Gpzz;
    i = i + 1;
    hh = hh + 1;
} while (A < D);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое Roman Goriachevskiy, вы мне очень помогли

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам просто нужно вынести создание массива за пределы цикла.
У вас каждый проход цикла создается новый массив.

```
double *Gpz = new double[hh];
do { 
    Gpzz = выражение; 
    Gpz[i] = Gpzz; 
    i = i + 1; 
    hh = hh + 1; 
} while (A < D);
```

Только вот не совсем понятен ваш код, зачем вы увеличиваете переменную которая определяет размер массива?

Comment: так я изначально не знаю размер массива, так как  не знаю через сколько проходов цикла условие выполнится

Comment: а никак нельзя сделать, чтоб он сохранялся и при этом размерность его менялась ?

Comment: Ну тогда если вы пишете на C++ вам может лучше использовать не динамические массивы, а к примеру контейнеры из стандартной библиотеки. Они сами выделят нужное количество памяти, а вам нужно будет просто добавлять туда элементы.


    std::vector<double> Gpz;
    do { 
        Gpzz = выражение; 
        Gpz.push_back(Gpzz);  
    } while (A < D);

Comment: я просто после Visual Basic переписываю программу в с++ и даже понятия не имею о контейнерах :(, не могли бы вы мне подсказать как это реализовать или где почитать об этом

Comment: Для того что бы он сохранялся и размерность менялась, вам нужно выделить новый массив большего размера, скопировать в него все из старого и удалить старый. ну а потом добавлять значения в новый пока его хватает и так каждый раз когда заканчивается массив.

Comment: спасибо, но смогу ли я из этого контейнера достать необходимое мне число при необходимости?

Comment: В гугле поищите информацию по STL ну или если знакомы с английским то вот http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: Да сможете достать, из вектора можно получать значения так же как и из обычного массива.    
К примеру...      

    std::vector<double> Gpz;
    
    Gpz.push_back(0);
    Gpz.push_back(1);
    Gpz.push_back(2);
    Gpz.push_back(3);
    Gpz.push_back(4);
    Gpz.push_back(5);
    
    double a = Gpz[3]; // a = 3
    // или использовать безопасную функцию доступа которая проверит не выходите ли вы за граници контейнера
    double b = Gpz.at(3); // b = 3